# How to display specific items in ng-repeat with ng-mouseover?

Tags: angularjs

I need to show an Edit icon on a particular element, but as hovering it shows the Edit icon on each element in ng-repeat. How can I achieve it using controllerAs?

Please provide me solution for the same. I'm able to achieve through normal behaviour($scope), but unable to get it through a controller.

`Here is the link -- >
enter code here`http://plnkr.co/edit/ETMyoDLR8HPFIZFrA90n?p=preview

Comment: you can use some conditional logic on ng-class for when to display and not. identify your base requirements and manipulate css

Comment: Hi @Ruchi, you can use ng-show/hide or ng-if inside ng-repeat.

Comment: Hi @Ruchi,  `<a ng-show="task.name=='The the second item'" >` replace your <a> that with the above code, and it will show only in for the second element. Hence please consider using similar logics. I hope this will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need. Instead of setting the `hoverEdit` with the controller use it instead with the `task`.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var ma = this;
  ma.tasks = [{
      name: 'Item One'
    },
    {
      name: 'The second item'
    },
    {
      name: 'Three items is the best'
    }
  ];

  ma.hoverIn = function(task) {
    task.hoverEdit = true;
  };

  ma.hoverOut = function(task) {
    task.hoverEdit = false;
  };

});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

li {
  width: 200px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background: #EEE;
}

.animate-show {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ma">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="task in ma.tasks" ng-mouseover="ma.hoverIn(task)" ng-mouseleave="ma.hoverOut(task)">
      {{task.name}}
      <span ng-show="task.hoverEdit" class="animate-show">
                <a>
                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519584-081_Pen-16.png" alt="">
                    Edit
                </a>
            </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use $index to set the index to hoverEdit

```
ma.hoverIn = function(index){
    ma.hoverEdit = index;
};

ma.hoverOut = function(){
    ma.hoverEdit = null;
};
```

checking if you are hovering the index and display it using ng-show

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="task in ma.tasks" ng-mouseover="ma.hoverIn($index)" ng-mouseleave="ma.hoverOut()">
        {{task.name}}
        <span ng-show="ma.hoverEdit == $index" class="animate-show">
            <a>
                <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519584-081_Pen-16.png" alt="">
                Edit
            </a>
        </span>
    </li>
```

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bGzn54KGrHw9LZr8tVzK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution please have a look into this added [`plunker code`](http://plnkr.co/edit/ps6sQ0k8ayOltWKeQiKR?p=preview).

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ma">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in ma.tasks" ng-mouseover="ma.hoverIn(task)" ng-mouseleave="ma.hoverOut(task)">
            {{task.name}}
            <span ng-show="task.hoverEdit" class="animate-show">
                <a>
                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519584-081_Pen-16.png" alt="">
                    Edit
                </a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    var ma=this;
    ma.tasks = [
        {name: 'Item One', hoverEdit : false},
        {name: 'The second item', hoverEdit : false},
        {name: 'Three items is the best', hoverEdit : false}
    ];

    ma.hoverIn = function(obj){
        obj.hoverEdit = true;
    };

    ma.hoverOut = function(obj){
        obj.hoverEdit = false;
    };

});
```